# PHP - calling a private method for testing, what's the correct design?

Tags: php, unit-testing, private-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PhpUnit private method testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937845/phpunit-private-method-testing)

In my unit tests I need to call a private method to set my fixtures to a given state. On the other hand, I'd rather not make this method public. How do I go about this?

Comment: Thanks, I'm flagging it for closing then. Sorry I didn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make those functions protected and create a derived class for testing purposes? That class can have public functions for testing that can initialize the various variables etc.

Comment: And it's not necessary to have a subclass - you can just mock such class. Of course, it will create subclass with randomized name, but you do not need to make a subclass by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing private methods is generally a bad idea, but if you really want to, reflection is the way to go. This should do it:

```
$reflection_class = new ReflectionClass($object_under_test);
$method = $reflection_class->getMethod('nameOfMethod');
$method->setAccessible(true);
$method->invoke($object_under_test, $param);
```

HTH