# PHPUnit - Stub private method in mock

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, stub

I am writing PHP Unit test and I have class with public method `testMeMethod` (which I want to test) and private method `privateMethod` (which is called by public method). I am mocking my class like this:

```
$constructorArgs = array(
   'foo',
   'void'
);

$myMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\some\namespace\MockMeClass')
            ->setConstructorArgs($constructorArgs)
            ->getMock();
```

But this will make all methods stubs and I need to test my public method. I need stub just private method, so I tried:

```
$myMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\some\namespace\MockMeClass')
            ->setConstructorArgs($constructorArgs)
            ->setMethods(array('privateMethod'))
            ->getMock();

$myMock->expects($this->any())->method('privateMethod')->will($this->returnValue('Return this'));
```

But even after that, if I call:

```
$myMock->testMeMethod();
```

Actual public method code is processed, but for private method too. Why is not private method overwritten to simply return `Return this` without running actual code?

Comment: One solution is change private method to protected, but I don't like it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937845/mock-private-method-with-phpunit?rq=1

Comment: You could use Reflection and then mark the class as public to access it.